# Modal window on ajax success handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I'm trying to open a modal window after a made ​​via ajax request through the success handler , however the theme I'm using uses a plugin to own ajax , and modal windows are not showing up

sorry 4 my bad english

```
$.ajax({
                            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/projects/biblioteca/php/cadastrar-autor.php',
                            type: "POST",
                            data: {autor1 : autor},
                            dataType: 'html',
                            success: function(data) {
                               if (data == 'ok') {
                                $.modal.alert('clicado');                                   
                               }
                            },
                            error: function(data)
                              {
                               alert('Servidor não respondendo, tente novamente');
                              }
                        });
                     }
```

If i put `$.modal.alert('clicado');`    on `$(document).ready` the modal windows shows normally, but inside the ajax don't.

Comment: Try logging what the value of $ is inside that function. I think there is a collision of `this` somewhere in your success handler

Comment: this is what i got from console.log($) =  function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}

Comment: there is nothing else that immediately suggests this shouldn't be working. You could try changing you success handler to

`success: function(data) {
   code goes here
}.bind(this)`

If doesn't work then it definitely isn't a scoping issue and we will need more context to understand what is going on.

Comment: i think i got it, i store $.modal(...) on a variable, and call this variable on ajax and it working, but it seems ajax is refreshing my page so the modal window desappear disappear quickly.